# Is there a female equivalent for "my good sir"?

Tags: expressions

Is there a quaint-sounding/archaic dual to address women *a la* "[my] [good] sir" jovially in casual conversation?  I can't come up with an expression that doesn't sound like a moderately intense term of endearment (e.g. *my [fair] lady*).  Can you even sound quaint but still be modern?

Comment: I don't consider *lady* to be as endearing as you. Perhaps *madam* or even *woman* (i.e. "my good woman")? This question may be a better fit at [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) as it's open-ended and likely to lead to extended debate or discussion.

Comment: "Madam" works as a female equivalent in most places where for a man you would say "sir". "Lady" is the female equivalent of "gentleman".

Comment: The female knights I know all prefer *dame* as the feminine version of *sir*, but somehow, "my good dame" just doesn't really work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How "lady" is going to be received really depends on your audience. That said, some options are:

> My good lady 
> My lady 
> My good woman 
> Madam 
> Woman

A lot will depend on context, too, as well as tone.

Comment: My mother-in-law reported being disgusted by a colleague from the American south addressing her as "the little lady."

Comment: Madam was my first thought....nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

*My dear lady* would sound quaint. [It was used by Shakespeare.](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/quotes/shakespeareonfate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Context is lacking in the question, but as woman I would generally consider it sweet, workplace excluded,  for a man to address me as *kind lass* (or *lovely lass* if his intention is to flirt).

Answer (score 0):

I used to date someone that lovingly called me "little lady" in my young-20's. I think if used the right way it can be very endearing. He would reach out and address me saying "Hey little lady!" I call people "sir" a lot and he may have been trying to mirror that language. I think that's a way to sound quaint and modern.

I've also called my younger cousin "little lady" when addressing her because she's young, bright, and for many years little.

However, I wouldn't use this to address an older woman like my mother. I think then "little" might have connotation ties with having "grown little" or shorter with age. However, this is all just my personal opinion. For an older woman, I might say "thank you, Miss" because even if they are married (and quite obviously a "Mrs.") I think if I were older, it would make me feel young or remind me of when I was a wee tot and so I find it a playful rendition for addressing older women, if done in the right way.